# Why does my Form mail script not work?

Tags: php, forms, email

I've searched a script on the internet to let send a form to your email. But when I press the submit button, i'll come to the thank you page. So it should have been send. But it isn't.
Can someone help me out?

Send Script:

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "dj-sam@live.nl";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$naam = $_REQUEST['naam'] ;
$wedstrijd1 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd1'] ;
$wedstrijd2 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd2'] ;
$wedstrijd3 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd3'] ;
$wedstrijd4 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd4'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
$injections = array('(\n+)',
'(\r+)',
'(\t+)',
'(%0A+)',
'(%0D+)',
'(%08+)',
'(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['naam'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($naam) || empty($wedstrijd1) || empty($wedstrijd2) || empty($wedstrijd3) || empty($wedstrijd4) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($naam) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Nieuwe voorspelling ingestuurd!",
$naam,
$wedstrijd1,
$wedstrijd2,
$wedstrijd3,
$wedstrijd4);
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP mail method is defined on the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) as

mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

which maps to you code as

$to = $webmaster_email

$subject = Nieuwe voorspelling ingestuurd!

$message = $naam

$additional_headers = $wedstrijd1

$additional_parameters = $wedstrijd2

and i'm guessing you wish $wedstrijd1 etc to be part of the message

Therefor in my opinion the best way to return the information from the from would be to place all the variables in a formatted message for sending

```
$message = "Name = {$naam}\n"
    ."Competition 1 = {$wedstrijd1}\n"
    ."Competition 2 = {$wedstrijd2}\n"
    ."Competition 3 = {$wedstrijd3}\n"
    ."Competition 4 = {$wedstrijd4}\n";

mail( $webmaster_email, "Nieuwe voorspelling ingestuurd!", $message);
```

The additional_headers is traditionally used for setting the likes of From, Cc, and Bcc

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the mail command.  If you take a look at the [documentation for mail](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php) you can see that you are now overriding the additional headers.  If you are not feeding it a FROM address in the additional headers, it will fail to send.  Without the additional parameters, it uses whatever is in the php config file as the default.

It appears that the parameters you are passing in are intended as part of the message body of the e-mail, however the mail command only takes a single string as the message body.  You must concatenate the string input prior to calling mail and pass the entire subject as a single parameter.

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "dj-sam@live.nl";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$naam = $_REQUEST['naam'] ;
$wedstrijd1 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd1'] ;
$wedstrijd2 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd2'] ;
$wedstrijd3 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd3'] ;
$wedstrijd4 = $_REQUEST['wedstrijd4'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
$injections = array('(\n+)',
'(\r+)',
'(\t+)',
'(%0A+)',
'(%0D+)',
'(%08+)',
'(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['naam'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($naam) || empty($wedstrijd1) || empty($wedstrijd2) || empty($wedstrijd3) || empty($wedstrijd4) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($naam) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
    $message = $naan . $wedstrijd1 . $wedstrijd2 . $wedstrijd3 . $wedstrijd4;
    if( mail( "$webmaster_email", "Nieuwe voorspelling ingestuurd!", $message))
    {
        header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
    }
    else
    {
        header( "Location: $error_page" );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: But when I delete all "wedstrijd" 1, 2, 3 and 4 the email will send. The code where im talking about: // If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Nieuwe voorspelling ingestuurd!",
  $naam,
  $wedstrijd1,
  $wedstrijd2,
  $wedstrijd3,
  $wedstrijd4);
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}

Comment: @change1001 Are you sending it from your house using a development server?

Comment: @AJHenderson So how do I fix that? (reply to your edit)

Comment: @change1001 - well that depends on what you are passing in for those parameters.  You need to make sure to pass the from data if you actually need those extra headers.  If you are just doing basic mail, then you shouldn't need them.

Comment: @AJHenderson i don't really understand what you are saying. Im really new to coding...

Comment: @change1001 - in that case, drop those parameters entirely.  Unless you are doing something special, you do not need them.  If you don't understand what they do, then you most likely do not need them.

Comment: @change1001 - See my updated version of your script.  It removes the unneeded headers for basic e-mail sending and adds verification of the success of the mail() operation.

Comment: @AJHenderson but where are my other variables that needs to be in the mail? Variables: $wedstrijd1, $wedstrijd2, $wedstrijd3, $wedstrijd4

Comment: @change1001 - what do you think is in those?  From your script, they don't appear to have any purpose.

Comment: @AJHenderson now they don't, because you've deleted them from the script :P

Comment: @change1001 - what are you passing in to them?  I have a feeling you are not using them correctly in your original code.  If you are trying to assemble a message from parameters being passed in, you must assemble the string prior to the mail() call.  The mail call takes a single string as the message body, the other stuff is e-mail headers which you don't seem to know what they are, so you wouldn't be setting them.

Comment: @AJHenderson I'm using them to link some text, just the same as the "naam" variable

Comment: @change1001 - it won't be a link unless you format the e-mail as HTML and build the entire HTML document.  The contents of the e-mail will be whatever text is in naan in your code.  I have updated it to work from $message in my code and have concatenated the inputs together, but you will likely need more work in order to get the contents of the e-mail properly built in $message.

Comment: @AJHenderson Thanks for your help. But i'm too nooby to do this ^^. I don't need any help anymore